# Busy WebServer Apache bombing and seems to not obey ulimit set for it

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I am seeing the following entries in Apache's error log

```
[Mon Jul 04 13:39:27 2011] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48
[Mon Jul 04 13:39:27 2011] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48
[Mon Jul 04 13:39:27 2011] [alert] Child 13286 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Mon Jul 04 13:39:27 2011] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48
[Mon Jul 04 13:39:27 2011] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48

cat /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     1024
apache          soft    nproc           8800
apache          hard    nproc           65000


#Apache conf info 

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       80
MinSpareServers    100
MaxSpareServers   101
ServerLimit     2100
MaxClients      2100
MaxRequestsPerChild  3000
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache runs as root, and then it suid to the apache user.
The nproc setting for the apache user will not work, try increasing the nproc setting for all users:

```
*   soft   nproc   8000
```

Either do this on the 90-nproc.conf file, or comment it and do it on the /etc/security/limits.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Limits defined in `/etc/security/limits.d` or `limits.conf` will not apply to programs which call `setuid`, unless it is specified so in the PAM modules.

You can enable this behavior by adding the line:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

to these files:

- /etc/pam.d/common-session
- /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive